# How to move game object forward despite of world axises?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I`m writing a script, where I control the camera by pushing buttons and by mouse. I need camera always moves forward(where View Frustum is directed ), but it moves only on world axises. How to do it?

Comment: Can you supply the code you're using to move the camera? I suspect you're using `Vector3.forward` instead of `transform.forward`, which is what you need.

Comment: When dealing with vectors in Unity3d, `Vector3` is world space, while `transform` is local space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
    MyCamera.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward);
```

To move the camera forward, where MyCamera is of course your camera.